# Creating a table with many optional fields

Tags: schema, normalization

I am a developer (student) looking for some advice on what best approach should I follow while creating a table to model an entity that has a number of optional fields.

There exists a need to model an `Organization` entity with a few key fields such as `id` and `name`. There is also a join table from `Users` to `Organization` that specifies who belongs to the `Organization` and what their role(s) are.

The question I have pertains to a number of optional fields that belong to the `Organization`, such as `website`, `email`, and `social links`. Below are my ideas of approaching the problem thus far:

1. Add them to the table as optional fields

   - Pros: Easy CRUD on one table, faster than navigating joins, etc.
   - Cons: It seems a bit dirty to me. Might it become difficult to do migrations in the future?
2. Create a `contact_information` table that references an `organization_id`, references a `contact_type_id` (of website, email, Facebook, etc.) from a lookup table, and has a generic `value` field for the actual content.

   - Pros: feels cleaner, allows for an arbitrary number of contact types in the future
   - Cons: probably a lot slower. Tons more tables.

I am leaning towards #2, because it is a similar approach to what I'm doing for physical addresses, but I'm unsure whether or not it is the best solution as DBA is not my forte. If there is a 3rd or even 4th option that I am unaware of, I'd be really interested to hear of those as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second option is more flexible, but I'm not sure why you're worried about "tons more tables". Usually this would be done with a single table:

```
contact_types
-------------
  id (PK)
  name

contact_details
---------------
  id
  contact_type_id (FK to contact_types.id)
  value

organization_contacts
---------------------
  id (PK)
  contact_detail_id (FK to contact_details)
  organization_id (FK to organizations)
```

populated like this:

```
contact_types
-------------
ID  | name
----+-----------
1   | web_url
2   | facebook_url
3   | phone_1

contact_details
---------------
id  | type_id  | value
----+----------+-------
1   | 1        | www.stuff.com
2   | 3        | (111) 111-1111
3   | 2        | facebook.com/?profileid=stuff

organization_contacts
---------------------
id | contact_detail_id  | organization_id
---+--------------------+----------------
1  | 1                  | 1
2  | 2                  | 1
3  | 3                  | 1
```

This schema only has 3 tables (not "tons") and you can have as many contact types as you want. The joins aren't that complicated. Your `contact_details` table will be large as there is 1 record per piece of contact info, but unless you have "tons" of contact info for each organization and "tons" or organizations, this probably won't be too big a problem. ;)

You could also have a `contact_details` table which stores all of the fields. Something like this:

```
contact_details
---------------
  id (PK)
  main_email
  secondary_email
  web_url
  facebook_url
  linkedin_url
  myspace_url
  street_address_line_1
  street_address_line_2
  street_address_line_3
  city
  prov_state
  country
  postal_code
  phone_num_1
  phone_num_2
  fax_num
```

This structure is much simpler but is more static. If you don't plan to change your set of contact data very much, and you think that *most* records will have most (or above a certain threshold of) fields filled out, I suspect this would perform better.

Comment: I can't see a reason for having `contact_details` table while we can place `type_id` and `value` columns into `organization_contracts`.

Answer (score 4):

I personally like the second option best. This is a fairly common way to solve this problem. Consider adding a "default_contact_type_id" column to your organization table for quicker lookups and/or reporting.

Option 3: For the sake of completeness, you could add an XML column to the organization table calles simply "contact_information". An XML blob can store all sorts of contact information and gives you a lot of modelling freedom (like providing country code and area code for phone numbers, zip code, state for postal address, and so on) but it'll probably cause you a significant performance hit once you get some volumes in there.